# Is there a way to access a Css style through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to access a variable from a css using Jquery? I have a function that once clicked it moves a div to the left -100%, I have another button that once clicked moves the div left -200%. I want to be able to gather information to know if the div's position left is 0%, -100%, or -200%.

Here is my current Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#about').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
        $('#main_div_wide_wrapper').animate({
        'left' : '-=100%' //moves left
        });
    });

});
```

I want to be able to know what `#main_div_wide_wrapper`'s position left is.

Comment: Yes. Best is to visit its [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) when searching for capabilities.

Comment: `$('#main_div_wide_wrapper').css('left')`. http://api.jquery.com/css/, as explained in the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/).

Comment: `$('#main_div_wide_wrapper').position().left;`

Answer (score 3):

It's easy, you can use `$("#main_div_wide_wrapper").css("left");`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Rico Note that this person couldn't really comment (less than 50 reputation) and I think the answer is totally legitimate..